# Vertical Align images with hyperlink in Table

Tags: html, html-table

Hello Everyone and thank you for your assistance. I am having issues with some images I have. I got it into a table because I needed the pictures next to each other but I also would like them vertically aligned.

```
<table><tr><td style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="http://www.dummywebsite.org/" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://www.dummyurl.com/blank1.jpg" alt="" width="225" height="225" style="display:inline"/></a>
</td><td>
    <a href="http://www.dummyfoundation.org/" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://www.dummyurl.com/blank2.png" alt="" width="300" height="88"  style="display:inline"/>
</td></tr></table>
```

Is it a style that is used for the table row that vertically aligns it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple technics. Ie: flexbox:

```
a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

You got also unclosed `<a>` tag in the second `<td>`.

Read more about flex here: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/